# How to set own scoring with GridSearchCV from sklearn for regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, scoring, gridsearchcv

I used to use GridSearchCV(...scoring="accuracy"...) for classification model. and now I am about to use GridSearchCV for the regression model and set scoring with own error function.

Example code:

```
def rmse(predict, actual):
    predict = np.array(predict)
    actual = np.array(actual)

    distance = predict - actual

    square_distance = distance ** 2

    mean_square_distance = square_distance.mean()

    score = np.sqrt(mean_square_distance)

    return score

rmse_score = make_scorer(rmse)

gsSVR = GridSearchCV(...scoring=rmse_score...)
gsSVR.fit(X_train,Y_train)
SVR_best = gsSVR.best_estimator_
print(gsSVR.best_score_)
```

However, I found it this way return parameter set when the error score is the highest. as a result, I got the worst parameter set and score. In this case, how can I get the best estimator and score?

summary:

classification -> GridSearchCV(scoring="accuracy") -> best_estimaror...best

regression -> GridSearchCV(scroing=rmse_score) -> best_estimator...worst

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a technically a loss where lower is better. You can turn that option on in [`make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html):

> **greater_is_better** : boolean, **default=True** Whether score_func is a
>   score function (default), meaning high is good, or a loss function,
>   meaning low is good. In the latter case, the scorer object will
>   sign-flip the outcome of the score_func.

You also need to change the order of inputs from `rmse(predict, actual)` to `rmse(actual, predict)` because thats the order GridSearchCV will pass them. So the final scorer will look like this:

```
def rmse(actual, predict):

    ...
    ...
    return score

rmse_score = make_scorer(rmse, greater_is_better = False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! However, in that case, i got negative score when GridSearchCV.best_score_

Comment: @willPark Yes. Just invert that sign to get actual loss value. Nothing is different. Its just designed this way so that a single logic can handle both type of values (scores and losses).